# Intro slider accessible with hidden bottom navigation

Tags: react-native, slider, react-navigation

I am trying to use [Intor slider](https://github.com/Jacse/react-native-app-intro-slider) I am able to make it run when loading app, but not sure how to run it from any screen and full screen, the bottom navbar is always visible.

App.tsx

```
 export default () => {
  const navigation = useRef(null);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigation}>
        <App navigation={navigation} />
        {/* GLOBAL FLASH MESSAGE COMPONENT INSTANCE */}
        <FlashMessage position="top" />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

return App:

```
 const _onDone = () => {
    setShowApp(true);
  }

  if (showApp) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Spinner visible={uiLoading} textContent={'Loading...'} />
        {userAuthenticated ? <TabNavigator /> : <AuthNavigtor />}
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
      <AppIntroSlider
        keyExtractor={_keyExtractor}
        renderItem={_renderItem}
        data={data}
        onDone={_onDone}
      />
    </View>)
  }
```

This is working fine when opening the app because navigation is hidden.

I want to create component just for slider:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
      <AppIntroSlider
        keyExtractor={_keyExtractor}
        renderItem={_renderItem}
        data={data}
        onDone={_onDone}
      />
    </View>
```

How I can set that navigation is hidden when I return the slider?